# union merge or fulljoin in R

Tags: r, join, merge, union

I have two datasets to join as a union(full join)

dataset 1 has variables a-d and dataset 2 has variables e-f.

If I run `full_join(dataset1, dataset2, by="id")`,

it only shows all of the rows in dataset1, the intersection of dataset1 and 2, but not the ones that have values only in(for the variable e-f) dataset 2.

More specifically,

```
id a b c d
 1 1 0 0 0
 2 1 0 0 0
 3 0 1 0 0
 4 0 0 1 0
 5 0 0 1 1
```

```
id e f
 1 1 0
 3 1 0
 5 0 1
 6 1 1
 7 0 0
```

If I fully join these two, the result I want is as follows.

```
id  a  b  c  d  e  f
 1  1  0  0  0  1  0
 2  1  0  0  0 NA NA
 3  0  1  0  0  1  0
 4  0  0  1  0 NA NA   
 5  0  0  1  1  0  1
 6 NA NA NA NA  1  1
 7 NA NA NA NA  0  0
```

But the result I get is as follows, without the rows with id=6, 7

```
id  a  b  c  d  e  f
 1  1  0  0  0  1  0
 2  1  0  0  0 NA NA
 3  0  1  0  0  1  0
 4  0  0  1  0 NA NA
 5  0  0  1  1  0  1
```

Can anyone help me debug this, please?

Comment: Please provide the data in a fashion that is easier to work with. Either wrap the data an a working `data.frame()` / `tibble:::tribble()` commands or use `dput()` on the objects in your R environment and paste the output here.

Comment: `full_join(data.frame(id = 1:2, a = "a"), data.frame(id = 2:3, b = "b"))` works for me. Can you provide a similar example that demonstrates the problem by not working? Using `dput()` as Till suggests is the best way to share data.

Answer (score 1):

Lacking your code, I can reproduce your problem with:

```r
merge(df1, df2, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
#   id a b c d  e  f
# 1  1 1 0 0 0  1  0
# 2  2 1 0 0 0 NA NA
# 3  3 0 1 0 0  1  0
# 4  4 0 0 1 0 NA NA
# 5  5 0 0 1 1  0  1
```

And I can fix it with

```r
merge(df1, df2, by = "id", all = TRUE)
#   id  a  b  c  d  e  f
# 1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0
# 2  2  1  0  0  0 NA NA
# 3  3  0  1  0  0  1  0
# 4  4  0  0  1  0 NA NA
# 5  5  0  0  1  1  0  1
# 6  6 NA NA NA NA  1  1
# 7  7 NA NA NA NA  0  0
```

Similarly, if you're using `dplyr`,

```r
### incorrect
dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = "id")
#   id a b c d  e  f
# 1  1 1 0 0 0  1  0
# 2  2 1 0 0 0 NA NA
# 3  3 0 1 0 0  1  0
# 4  4 0 0 1 0 NA NA
# 5  5 0 0 1 1  0  1

### correct
dplyr::full_join(df1, df2, by = "id")
#   id  a  b  c  d  e  f
# 1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0
# 2  2  1  0  0  0 NA NA
# 3  3  0  1  0  0  1  0
# 4  4  0  0  1  0 NA NA
# 5  5  0  0  1  1  0  1
# 6  6 NA NA NA NA  1  1
# 7  7 NA NA NA NA  0  0
```

---

Data

```r
# dput(df1)
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:5, a = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), b = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), c = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), d = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
# dput(df2)
df2 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L), e = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), f = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```